# Adding "padding" to the outside of div?

Tags: css

I'm really not sure how to word this question, but here goes...  I have a navigation bar at the top of my web page with a position of "fixed" so that it stays at the top even if I scroll down.  However, I have a box that will hold all of my text/blogs that overlaps with this navigation bar whenever I scroll down.

Is there a way to "delete" a few pixels of the box (the one that holds all of my stuff) so that the navigation bar never overlaps with it?  I'm sorry if this is confusing, but like I said, I'm not sure how to word it.

**Screenshots:**
When I'm not scrolled down- [image]
When I am (overlapping)- [image]

So I want to get rid of the overlapped area of my content container (and maybe 5px below it).

Comment: Can you show a screenshot, please?

Comment: "padding on the outside" is called a "margin", and css supports it. you can use negative margins too if it helps.

Comment: Also, please show the relevant html and css snippet. I posted example guesses in my answer, but if you show your actual code it would much easier to help you.

Comment: @Mark I've tried margins, but they don't give the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are spot on. I'd check the margins, and the overflow setting.

If the div's have absolute, relative, or fixed positioning, you can also play around with the z-index.

The higher the value of the z-index, the higher up in the stack an element is. So an element with a z-index of 2 will be displayed in front of an element with a z-index of 1.

Comment: That would work, but my divs have transparency.  I posted some screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

On the box that contains your main content, add a margin-top equal to the height of the navigation bar. For example, if this is your html:

```
<div id="navbar">...</div>
<div id="content">...</div>
```

Then your css would be something like this:

```
#navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for the screen shots.

```
#navbar_id {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 50px;
    z-index: 25;
}

#main_stuff_id {
    z-index: 24;
    /*other
    style
    rules*/
}
```

keep in mind the "css box model" too:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/box-model.gif

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to enforce a margin on an element with `position: fixed;` set. I don't think this will work, but you could put a fixed-position container around the element which you want to actually be fixed. This container can have padding, which will then give the desired effect.

```
<div style="position:fixed;padding:16px;background-color:#fff;width:100%;box-sizing:border-box">
    <!-- don't fix the inner element -->
    <div style="background-color:red">The content you want to be fixed.</div>
</div>
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qtHtY/

Comment: The problem is that my divs have transparency.

Comment: In that case, I don't think you can scroll with the body. You could set up a scrollable DIV beneath the fixed content.

Answer (score -1):

Or if you are using `position` you can then use `top: #px;` and `left: #px`

Comment: I know how to set the position, I just want to know how to "pad" the outside of my navigation bar.

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this a couple hours ago, now I can't change my vote unless the question's edited. Sorry.